# Storage Access Framework - get available storages

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Can I somehow find out which storages are currently available WITHOUT starting the document picker and let the user select a directory?

I want to display all storage roots like following:

```
File mainRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// any root path that is available => I don't need access rights here, I just want to know which storages are available and "mounted"
DocumentFile sdCardRoot = ???;
DocumentFile usbCardRoot = ???;
DocumentFile gDriveRoot = ???;
```

**Why?**

Actually I want to know if an sd card is available before telling the user that he needs to select the sd cards root directory via the document picker...

So I want following:

1. check if an sd card is available
2. if not, do nothing
3. if an sd card is available, tell the user that my app needs permissions to read the sd card and ask the user to select the sd cards root directory via the storage access framework

The same I want to do for the usb stick, but there I know how to do it (there broadcast receivers exist to get notified when an usb stick is added and I can check if on is already connected as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    //Ask for the permission

    File externalRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); //gives the root directory of External storage
}
```

**Edit:**

Go to your .android\avd\"avd_name".avd folder , and open config.ini ; Make sure you have ,

```
hw.sdCard=yes
sdcard.size=100M
sdcard.path=[Path to ".android" directory]/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_23.avd/sdcard.img
```

Comment: just tried that in the android 6 emulator with an sd card mounted and it returns false in your if...

Comment: I tested it on my side (android 6 emulator), and it goes inside the `if` loop. Can you post your code?

Comment: My code is very simple, I just try following:  `public static boolean isSDCardMounted()
    {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
            return true;
        return false;
    }`

Comment: Log the value of `state` variable before going in the if block. What do you get in it?

Comment: The state is "removed". But when opening `settings/storage&usb` I can see my sd card in the emulator... And can access it and see the data on it...

Comment: I checked it and it's there. I've set up the avd via android studios avd manager and I configured an sd card. And in androids file explorer I can see the sd card...

Comment: Please post your `config.ini` file in the question.

Comment: See the edited answer. Add the path to your sdcard image.

Comment: Android studios setup let's you select an sd card file or "android studio managed". I've chosen second option, I think that's why the sd card path is missing in my `config.ini`... Adding it does not change anything...

Comment: In case of "Android studio managed", the path should be there. If you are using an external file make sure it is not corrupted or anything. Also, try creating an emulator again, if nothing works.

Comment: Got the sd card working now correctly... But as I supposed, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the primary storage path which is my internal storage... I'll remove the `config.ini` again from my question...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing I came up until now:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
DocumentFile sdCardRoot = null;

File[] fs = context.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
// at index 0 you have the internal storage and at index 1 the real external...
if (fs != null && fs.length >= 2)
{
    String mainPath = fs[0].getAbsolutePath();
    String subPath = mainPath.replace(root.getFolder().getAbsolutePath(), "");
    String pathSDCard = fs[1].getAbsolutePath().replace(subPath, "");
    String relTreePath = pathSDCard.substring(1).replace("storage", "tree") + "%3A";
    // this string is defined com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider... but seems to not be accessable in code...
    Uri treeUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents"), relTreePath);
    sdCardRoot = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri);
}

// now you have the internal storage root in "root" - this path is directly readable via the `File` class
// and the sd card's root is in sdCardRoot and can be managed via the `DocumentFile` class...
```